# Add space before question mark and exclamation mark

Tags: php, regex

My client wants to have a space before exclamation marks and question marks. To ensure this always is done correctly I use the following script in php. This script removes any existing spaces and then puts a non-breaking space before all question marks and exclamation marks:

```
$text =  str_replace(' ?', '?', $text);
$text = str_replace('?', '&nbsp;?', $text);
$text = str_replace(' !', '!', $text);
$text = str_replace('!', '&nbsp;!', $text);
return $text;
```

This all works fine but I was wondering if there's a better way with Regex?

Comment: Thanks Dave for the reformatting - I always struggle with the code tag - the four spaces doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 5):

You may use

```
$text = "No? Oh ? And ! and!";
$text = preg_replace('~\s*([?!])~',  '&nbsp;$1', $text);
echo $text;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/nwNYAI)

**Details**:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace symbols
- `([?!])` - Group 1 capturing `?` or `!`

The replacement pattern only contains `&nbsp;` and the backreference to Group 1 contents to insert the captured text.

Answer (score 3):

Use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

With regex it would look like this:

```
preg_replace('/(\S)([?!])/', '$1 $2', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace("/\s?(!|?)/", "&nbsp;$1", $string);`